# How to access files inside of a folder that is inside of a ZipEntry

Tags: java, io, zip

Sorry for the confusing title. Basically I have a ZipFile that has a bunch of .txt files in it but also has one folder. The code I am showing below is finding that folder in the zip entries. I have done this part just fine. The problem is that once I find the folder it is a ZipEntry. Which does not happen to have any useful methods to get entries inside of that folder. The folder I am finding has more .txt files in it that I want to process (that is the main goal).

```
zipFile = new ZipFile(zipName);
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
    ZipEntry current = entries.nextElement();
    if(current.getName().equals(folderName)) {
         assertTrue(current.isDirectory());
        //Here is where I want to get the files in the folder 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`ZipEntry` has a method `isDirectory()` which

> Returns true if this is a directory entry. A directory entry is
>   defined to be one whose name ends with a '/'.

What you'll want to do is iterate over all the the entries (as you are doing) and get the `InputStream` for those that are inside the directory, ie. that have a path relative to the directory.

Say `folderName` has the value `"/zip/myzip/directory"`, then a file inside that directory will have a name as `"/zip/myzip/directory/myfile.txt"`. You can use the Java NIO `Path` api to help you

```
Path directory = Paths.get("/zip/myzip/directory"); // you get this directory path from the ZipEntry
Path file = Paths.get(current.getName());
if (file.startsWith(directory)) {
   // do your thing
}
```

You can get the `InputStream` as

```
zipFile.getInputStream(current);
```

**Note** that paths inside a Zip file will be relative to the root of the Zip location. If the zip is at

```
C:/Users/You/Desktop/myzip.zip
```

a folder directly inside the zip with show a path like

```
directory/
```

Answer (score -3):

Something like that may help you

```
final ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(filename);
for (final Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zf.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
final ZipEntry ze = e.nextElement();
if (!ze.isDirectory()) {
     final String name = ze.getName();
     //.....
    }
}
```

Enjoy it ;-)

Answer (score -3):

Actually there's a simpler way to do this.  If you know that the current entry is a directory then when using the ZipInputStream, the next element will automatically be whatever is in that directory.  For example, let's say your directory structure is this:

```
Dir1/A.txt Dir1/B.txt Dir2/C.txt D.txt
```

Then to access all three above you simply have to go about it this way :

```
ZipInputStream Zis = new ZipInputStream(in);
ZipEntry entry = Zis.getNextEntry();
while (entry != null) {
    if(!entry.isDirectory)
       //do something with entry  
    //else continue  
    entry = Zis.getNextEntry(); 
}
```

This will iterate through all the files (in the order they're listed) without having to explicitly check to see if they're directories since you're not doing anything different with them.